# Using Javascript FileReader in forEach loop to append elements

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the FileReader to insert HTML to a preview element. That parts works. However I need to manipulate the elements after they are inserted. When I try to select the inserted elements with (let previews = document.querySelectorAll('.fb-preview li');) I get and empty node array.

I was under the impression that forEach is blocking and by the time the loop finishes I should be able to select the inserted html elements.

Is there something I am missing about the FileReader or forEach loops?

It works if I add a setTimeout but that seems hackish.

```
items.forEach(v => {               
    const preview = document.querySelector('.fb-preview');
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
        switch (v.type) {
            case 'application/pdf':
                preview.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li><embed src=${reader.result}></i><span>${v.name}</span></li>`);
            break;
            case 'image/jpeg':
            case 'image/tiff':
            case 'image/gif':
            case 'image/png':
                preview.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li><img src="${reader.result}"></i><span>${v.name}</span></li>`);
            break;
            default:
                preview.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li><i class="fas fa-question-circle fa-fw"></i><span>${v.name}</span></li>`);
            break;
        }
    }, false);

    if (v) reader.readAsDataURL(v);        
});

let previews = document.querySelectorAll('.fb-preview li'); 
if (previews.length > 10) previews.forEach(e => e.style.height = '50%');
if (previews.length > 20) previews.forEach(e => e.style.height = '30%');
if (previews.length > 30) previews.forEach(e => e.style.height = '10%');
```

Comment: forEach is synchronous, but the actual DOM mutations happen in an event listener, which is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code shows that the DOM mutations happen in an event listener, which is asynchronous. The `forEach` loop only registers the listeners, it does not block while reading each files.

There is a better and easier way to accomplish your purpose: Blob URLs. You have a FileReader, so presumably you have Files to begin with ? File is a subclass of Blob, so you can use [`URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) on them. That gives you, synchronously, a relatively short "blob:" URL which references (but does not represent) the file's contents. Use that as the source of your images and embeds.